# RIP routes are not being advertised

Tags: cisco, routing, router, rip, loopback

I have 2 routers(R3 and R4 connected with serial links). I have advertised my loopbacks with RIP ver 2. with 192.168.1.1/32 and 192.168.2.1/32 on R3 and 192.168.3.1/32 and 192.168.4.1/32 on R4.
My routes are not being advertised, help me on this

```
Router3#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 912 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX15247K60-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.33.1.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Router4#sh run

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 912 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524QLWF-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 192.168.4.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.33.1.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 192.168.3.0
 network 192.168.4.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the link addresses (172.33.x.x) in the rip network statements.  Otherwise, RIP won't send advertisements out those interfaces.

Comment: BTW, 172.33.0.0/16 is a public subnet.  Be careful if you're connected to the Internet.

Comment: ohh yes yes i completely missed my connected link to advertise on RIP, thank you